# Why JS Event handlers are not working for elements created at runtime?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

```js
document.querySelector("#fire_button_creator_button").addEventListener("click",function () {
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(document.createElement("button")).innerText="now click me,i am fire button";
})

document.querySelector("#fire_button_creator_button+button").addEventListener("click",function () {
    document.querySelector("p").innerText="i am fired";
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="fire_button_creator_button">fire button creator</button>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to creat a button in runtime that can do somthing. Somthing like in my code it  inject some text inside `<p> </p>` tag **"i am fired"**. But i am getting errore. But why?. What is the solution(in vanilla javascript of course)?

Comment: You're getting the error because nothing in your document matches the selector `#fire_button_creator_button+button`

Comment: If you want to attach an event handler to the button that your first click handler is creating, you can do that only once you have actually created that button

Comment: A person in a room hands out id badges. A guy walks in late. Therefore he does no have a badge. Your JavaScript code does not keep checking for new elements. It runs once and is done. So if it is not there when it runs, it will never get the event. You either have to add the event when you create it or you have to use event delegation.

Comment: There are two errors - you can't add an event listener to the created button before it has been created, and adjacent sibling selectors must be adjacent: there's at least a paragraph element, and possibly script and other elements between the two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just assign the eventListener to the createdElement immediately instead of selecting it again (which won't work in your case, as the element doesn't even exist yet).

```js
document.querySelector("#fire_button_creator_button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    const button = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerText="now click me, i am fire button"
    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
       document.querySelector("p").innerText="i am fired";
    })
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(button)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="fire_button_creator_button">fire button creator</button>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelector("#fire_button_creator_button").addEventListener("click",function () {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(button).innerText="now click me,i am fire button";
  
    button.addEventListener("click",function () {
        document.querySelector("p").innerText="i am fired";
    })
})
```

You have to add the event listener AFTER the new button element is created.
You can do that like the code sample above or other way. The only important part is to do AFTER it is created, so an actual event listener is attached to an actual html element